# Why is XCode freaking out?? I.e., Xcode says methods & properties do not exist but they do!

Tags: iphone, xcode, gcc

XCode has been acting really, really strange recently. It is telling me that various classes' methods and properties do not exist - but they do! This is happening both with a custom class, and a Core Data class. I have declared all of the methods and properties, including all the necessary @synthesize calls, and have predeclared the classes using @class in the files which use them and included the .h files, but when I try to access the methods & properties - it throws errors or warnings, along the lines "No '+newMatrix' method found", "'Collection' may not respond to '+newMatrix'", and "Request for member 'isLanguage' in something not a structure or a union." These have all be declared properly - what could be causing XCode to choke?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether they are in the list of files being compiled. You might not have added the files.

For Core data did you include the Framework?

Comment: It is only one or two properties and methods - not the whole thing. And yes, the files are in the list of files compiled, and Core data works for everything except these one or two properties.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the right import statements - these two are very different:

```
#import <SDKLibrary.h>
#import "CustomClass.h"
```